# Extract string between slash

Tags: java, string

From the below URL, I am trying to extract 2 Strings i.e `String a = "region/country";` and `String b = "123xyz";` I tried using overloaded method of [IndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) but that too didnt help. Any pointers?

```
String URL = "http://abcd.com/region/country/state/123xyzCONSTANTTEXT.html";
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. And explain what the constant parts of the URL are: does it always start with `http://abcd.com/`, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **Pattern** class for this. If you want to match only the next two words after that url (that doesnt change) then you can use this. **\w** is a shorthand for **[a-zA-Z0-9_]**. If you are ok with **_** then use **\w** or else use **[a-zA-Z0-9]**.

The area inside the parenthesis is a **matching group**, if you want to separate out region and country simply put parenthesis around each of the **\w** individually and **matcher.group(1)** will contain *region* and **matcher.group(2)** will contain *country*

```
String URL = "http://abcd.com/region/country/state/123xyzCONSTANTTEXT.html";`

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://abcd.com/(\\w+/\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //prints region/country
} else {
    System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get Invalid escape sequence on the 2nd line. I have imported import java.util.regex.Pattern. Can you please confirm

Comment: Sorry bout that had a couple typos, just tested it and it fully works now.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `split()` method. It takes one argument in the form of a regex string and outputs an array of strings, split around the regex.

```
String[] stringArray = URL.split("/");
```

Will probably output an array like:

```
String[] stringArray = {"http:","","abcd.com","region","country","state","123xyzCONSTANTTEXT.html"};
```

And then use split again on an array index:

```
String[] stringArray2 = stringArray[7].split("CONSTANTTEXT.html");
```

To retrieve 123xyz, which will be stored in `stringArray2[0]`

Comment: @jeff_kile made a faster solution. Would `{\\w+?CONSTANTTEXT\.html}` work for the second group?

Comment: `String[] stringArray = URL.split("/");` is a bit confusing. There is no static method called `split("/");` on the `URL` class. Rather it should be `url.split("/");`

Comment: @pokkie In this case, `URL` is a variable. It should obviously be named `url` for readability purposes.

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
public class Example {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] string = "http://abcd.com/region/country/state/123xyzCONSTANTTEXT.html".split("/");

        String string1 = "";
        String string2 = "";

        for(int i =0; i < string.length ; i++) {
            if(i == 3) {
                string1 += string[i] + "/";
            }

            if(i == 4) {
                string1 += string[i];
            }

            if(i == 6) {
                string2 = string[i].substring(0, Math.min(string[i].length(), 6));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(string1);
        System.out.println(string2);
    }
}
```

output:

```
region/country
123xyz
```